# Upload image from current HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, devexpress

I have an image on my HMTL page.  This is generated by DevExpress library at runtime and the src url points to a DevExpress script with a cache key:

```
<img id="Chart_89_IMG" src="/DXB.axd?DXCache=30f02093-de66-4ed6-8557-2382065c701a" />
```

I'm trying to get this file onto the server in a subsequent form post to use in an email.  I've tried just passing the url in my form, but by the time it gets to the server, I get a 404 (assuming the cache key is expired).

I've also tried using `canvas` to get the bytes and pass that to the server, but was having trouble converting that byte stream back to an image, and canvas won't work for IE8, which I need to support.

My last idea was to include a file upload input on my form and pass the image to the server that way.  But, how can I create a file from an image in javascript to use as an upload?

Any other ideas would be appreciated too!

Answer (score 0):

Since this was DevExpress, I was able to change the BinaryStorageMode to the session:

```
settings.BinaryStorageMode = BinaryStorageMode.Session;
```

Then after I posted the form, the chart's bytes were accessible in the Session:

```
byte[] bytes = ((DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.BinaryStorageData)HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey]).Content;
```